# Adding/Deleting Data with Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I'm trying to use Entity Framework 4.0 to add and remove records with a many-to-many relationship. I've scoured the web but am just not finding a meaningful example.

As an example, let's say I have a Drivers and Vehicles table with a junction table VehicleDrivers.

Drivers

- DriverID
- ...

Vehicles

- VehicleID
- ...

VehicleDrivers

- DriverID
- VehicleID

My questions are:

1. How would I write EF statements to add a new vehicle and related driver?
2. How would I write EF statements to delete an existing vehicle and any related drivers?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

> How would I write EF statements to add a new vehicle and related
>   driver?

For existing driver:

```
using (var context = new MyContext(...))
{
    var newVehicle = new Vehicle { ... };
    var existingDriver = context.Drivers.First(d => d.Name == "Jim");
    newVehicle.Drivers.Add(existingDriver);

    context.Vehicles.AddObject(newVehicle);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

For new driver:

```
using (var context = new MyContext(...))
{
    var newVehicle = new Vehicle { ... };
    var newDriver = new Driver { ... };
    newVehicle.Drivers.Add(newDriver);

    context.Vehicles.AddObject(newVehicle);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

> How would I write EF statements to delete an existing vehicle and any
>   related drivers?

```
using (var context = new MyContext(...))
{
    var existingVehicle = context.Vehicles.First(v => v.Name == "Ford");

    context.Vehicles.DeleteObject(existingVehicle);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Nothing more to do here because the related entries in the join table with all drivers linked to the deleted vehicle will be deleted as well due to enabled cascading delete in the database.

**Edit**

If you want to delete the drivers as well (and not only the links) in a many-to-many relationship you need to check first if the driver isn't linked to another vehicle:

```
using (var context = new MyContext(...))
{
    var existingVehicle = context.Vehicles.Include("Drivers")
        .First(v => v.Name == "Ford");

    foreach(var driver in existingVehicle.Drivers.ToList())
    {
        if (!context.Drivers.Any(d => d.DriverId == driver.DriverId
            && d.Vehicles.Any(v => v.VehicleId != existingVehicle.VehicleId)))
            context.Drivers.DeleteObject(driver);
    }
    context.Vehicles.DeleteObject(existingVehicle);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Well, looking at just the delete code, it would cascade to the junction table, but deleting the junction table won't cascade to the drivers table. Indeed, it is possible that the driver is associated with other vehicles so it does not make sense to cascade deleting a vehicle to deleting all related drivers.

Comment: @Jonathan: Lol, I was just adding another example for the case you want also to delete the drivers. But as you say, in most cases in a many-to-many relationship this doesn't make much sense. But well, with the check in the example above it would work at least.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is use the key field and place it into the object I'm saving.  This does not work well when you are modifying several new objects at the same time however.